# Python(Jupyter Notebook): Display bar plot with columns as legends and index as x-ticks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

I have the following data with me

```
            AEPS    BBPS    Collect Money   Recharge    Transfers
Bin1    186.849   240.85    20               15.8333    735.789
Bin2    563.837   580.223   141.739          69.5152    2646.44
Bin3    1375.19   867.85    4327.39          169.456    6195.6
Bin4    5685.92   3557.5    32636.5          337.99     14300.3
```

I want to plot a bar graph with columns as my legends and indexes(Bin1  to Bin4) as my x-ticks with height equal to the amount corresponding to respective legend and x-ticks.

Comment: Does the given data belongs to `pandas` dataframe? If so, you can simply use `df.plot(kind='bar')`.

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot